# Gradient of the matrix function $trace\big((W \odot (A-UV'))'(W\odot (A-UV'))\big)$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-analysis

What is the gradient of the function w.r.to U ?.

$$
\operatorname{trace}\big((W \odot (A-UV'))'(W\odot (A-UV'))\big)
$$

Here, $\odot$ is the Hadamard product and $'$ is the transpose.  It seems like the gradient is $2(W\odot(UV'-A))V$.  Can anyone explain me how we get this ?

Comment: It seems strange to me, since the elements $W_{i,j}$ with $i\ne j$ don't  even appear in the original function..

Comment: @Exodd. In fact it is correct, if you look at this paper https://epubs.siam.org/doi/pdf/10.1137/1.9781611972801.18  equation 5.13

Comment: The article is correct. What you wrote is incorrect. The frobenius norm squared of $B$ is $tr(B'B)$ so if $B=W\odot (A-UV')$ you get $\|B\|_F^2 = tr( (W\odot (A-UV'))'(W\odot (A-UV')) )$

Comment: @Exodd, Yup.  It is a mistake from my side.  My original formulation was stated as sum of element-wise. When I re-wrote in matrix form, I forgot to take $W$ into consideration.  Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @Exodd, I corrected the question. Can you please explain me how can I find the gradient ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's use a colon to denote the trace/Frobenius product
$$A:B={\rm tr}(A^TB)$$
For typing convenience, let's also define two additional matrices
$$\eqalign{
 Y &= UV^T-A \cr
 X &= W\odot Y \cr
}$$
Write the function in terms of these new variables and find its differential and gradient
$$\eqalign{
 \phi &= X:X \cr
d\phi &= 2X:dX \cr
 &= 2X:(W\odot dY) \cr
 &= 2(W\odot X):dY \cr
 &= 2(W\odot X):dU\,V^T \cr
 &= 2(W\odot X)V:dU \cr
\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial U}
 &= 2(W\odot X)V \cr
 &= 2(W\odot W\odot Y)V \cr
 &= 2\Big(W\odot W\odot(UV^T-A)\Big)V \cr
}$$

Comment: when It comes to matrix gradients, your little trick about commutative property of Hadamard product and trace norm seems to work all the time.   In nutshell, ca we write $A:B\odot C  = A\odot B :C$ all the time ?

Comment: @Shew Yes, the Hadamard and Frobenius products always commute.

Comment: what is the correct equation, $A:B\odot C  = A\odot B :C$  or $A:B\odot C  = B\odot A :C$ ?.  Or both are valid ?

Comment: @Shew All three expressions are the same. The Hadamard and Frobenius products commute with themselves and each other.  In fact, you can also write it as $A\odot B\odot C:1$.

Answer (score 1):

Letting $X=W\circ(A - UV')$ then in terms of components we have
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial U_{mn} }\left( \operatorname{Tr}X'X \right) &= \frac{\partial}{\partial U_{mn}}\left( \sum_{i, j} X_{ij}^2 \right) \\
&= 2\sum_{i,j} X_{ij}\frac{\partial X_{ij}}{\partial U_{mn} } .
\end{align}
$$
Checking the components we have
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial X_{ij}}{\partial U_{mn} } &= \frac{\partial}{\partial U_{mn}} W_{ij} \cdot \left(A_{ij} - \sum_k U_{ik} V_{kj}' \right) \\
&= - \delta_{im} \cdot  W_{ij} \cdot V_{nj}', 
\end{align}
$$
and so
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial }{\partial U_{mn} }\operatorname{Tr}X'X &= 2\sum_{ij}X_{ij}\frac{\partial X_{ij}}{\partial U_{mn}}  \\ 
&= 2\sum_{i, j} W_{ij}\cdot\left(\sum_k U_{ik} V_{kj}' - A_{ij}\right)\delta_{im}W_{ij}V_{nj}' \\
&= 2\sum_j W^2_{mj} \left([UV']_{mj} - A_{mj}\right)V_{jn} \\
&= 2 \sum_j [(W\circ W)\circ(UV' - A )]_{mj}[V]_{jn} \\
&= 2 \left[\left((W\circ W)\circ (UV' - A)\right) V\right]_{mn}
\end{align}
or 
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial }{\partial U} \operatorname{Tr}(X'X) = 2\left(W^{\circ 2} \circ (UV' - A) \right) V
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Little trick: the product derivative rule works with matrix and Hadamard products too. It means that

$$
\frac d{dU_{i,j}}\operatorname{trace}\big((W \odot (A-UV'))'(W\odot (A-UV'))\big)
= $$$$
\operatorname{trace}\big(\frac d{dU_{i,j}}(W \odot (A-UV'))'(W\odot (A-UV'))  + (W \odot (A-UV'))'\frac d{dU_{i,j}}(W\odot (A-UV')) \big)=
$$$$
\operatorname{trace}\big((W \odot -e_ie_j^TV')'(W\odot (A-UV'))  + (W \odot (A-UV'))'(W\odot -e_ie_j^TV') \big)
$$
but $tr(X'Y+Y'X) = 2tr(X'Y)$ (this works when the matrices are real), so
$$
2\operatorname{trace}\big((W \odot -e_ie_j^TV')'(W\odot (A-UV'))  \big) =
2\operatorname{trace}\big((W' \odot Ve_je_i^T)(W\odot (UV'-A)) \big)
$$
It's easy to see that $W' \odot Ve_je_i^T = (W'e_i \odot Ve_j)e_i^T$ and if $v,w$ are vectors, then $tr(vw^T)=\sum v_iw_i$
$$
2\operatorname{trace}\big((W'e_i \odot Ve_j)e_i^T(W\odot (UV'-A)) \big) 
$$
$$
= 2 \sum_k W'_{ki}V_{kj}(W\odot (UV'-A))_{ik} = 2 \sum_k (W\odot (UV'-A))_{ik}W_{ik}V_{kj}
$$
$$
= 2 [(W\odot W\odot (UV'-A))V]_{ij}
$$

---

Notice: In the article, $W$ is an indicator matrix, so $W\odot W=W$ and you get the right result.